# How can I add a text input box when asked

Tags: php, javascript, html

So, I've seen websites where they ask you for some text in an input, but there's a "+" sign next to the input box where you can add another input box if required.

I'm new to all this, how can I do that?

Comment: Its done by adding more text box(es) to the DOM with javascript when the plus sign is clicked.

Comment: You need to present code here, not a requirement list and then ask us to build it for you.

Comment: Sure, if I had an idea of how to do it I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add elements to a [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) with the [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) method:

**Markup**:

```
<input type="button" value ="Add" id="btn" />
<div id="elements"></div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){

    var txt = document.createElement('input');
    txt.type = "text";
    document.getElementById("elements").appendChild(txt);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/QCxTN/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="multi-line-text-box-area">
   <input type="text">
</div>


var inputElement = '<input type="text">';
$("#multi-line-text-box-area").append(inputElement);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cv9rr/) is a fiddle illustrating that.